# How can i customize usercontrol from parent window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I want to know how can i change user control from my Parent window that i placed usercontrol into it.

I have an user control that have a grid and data grid in that. now i want change data grid properties in my window ... and i want add another control to my grid .
some thing like this

```
<window>
<usercontrol>
<usercontrol.datagrid backcolor=#ff00000>
<usercontrol/>
<window/>
```

or can i add a textblock into usercontrol grid like this code :

```
<window>
<usercontrol.grid>
<textblock grid.row=1/>
<usercontrol.grid/>
<window/>
```

All element in user control are **public** so i can make change from c# code but i want do that with **xaml** design mode

in windows form i create a user control inherit from data grid view then i custom it. i use it in 10 windows and in 11th window i need change data grid view a bit i dont change usercontrol because it change all windows so i just change that usercontrol is in 11th window
please help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should create a DependencyProperty for your DataGrid's BackgroundColor (or whatever property you want to change) inside your UserControl's code behind:

```
public static DependencyProperty GridColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("GridColor", typeof (Brush),
                                                                                         typeof (UserControl1),
                                                                                         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                                                                                             null,
                                                                                             FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions
                                                                                                 .AffectsRender));
        public Brush GridColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(GridColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GridColorProperty, value);}
        }
```

After that you should bind your DataGrid's Color property to it in UserControl's XAML:

```
<DataGrid Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=YourControlType}, Path=GridColor}"/>
```

And now you can use the control like that:

```
<YourControlType GridColor="Green"/>
```

As for controls addition it depends on what outlook exactly you're trying to achieve. The most straightforward way would be to derive your user control from grid. Or may be deriving from ContentControl would be enough for your purposes

Edit:
That's how you could put inside a new control. Deriving your control from Grid:

```
<Grid x:Class="WpfApplication3.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:app="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3" mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=app:YourControlType}, Path=GridColor}"/>
</Grid>
```

And you would use it like that:

```
<YourControlType GridColor="Green">
            <Button Grid.Row="1"/>
</YourControlType>
```

But actually it's a pretty weird thing to do and I would better derive it from a ContentControl:

```
<ContentControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.YourControlType"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:app="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3" mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <DataGrid Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=app:YourControlType}, Path=GridColor}"/>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

That's how you use it:

```
<YourControlType GridColor="Green">
       <Button/>
</YourControlType>
```

As yet another possibility you could create a dependency property for your control's content. Code behind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("InnerContent", typeof (FrameworkElement), typeof (YourControlType),
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(FrameworkElement),
                                                                      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

        public FrameworkElement InnerContent
        {
            get { return (FrameworkElement) GetValue(InnerContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InnerContentProperty, value); }
        }
```

UserControl's XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=WpfApplication3:UserControl1}, Path=GridColor}"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=app:YourControlType}, Path=InnerContent}"/>
</Grid>
```

Usage:

```
<YourControlType GridColor="Green">
    <YourControlType.InnerContent>
        <Button/>
    </YourControlType.InnerContent>
</YourControlType>
```

But if you want just a quick and simple answer to your initial question as it states, there is no way you can directly address an inner control of your UserControl from XAML. = )

Comment: Thanks was help full i read the last lines of your message late you answer all question:)

Comment: wow it was clear and simple answer ... it help a lot to me . thanks ;)